# StaleElementReferenceException thrown ONLY in the pipeline

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, e2e-testing

I have a test running in our azure pipeline that fails <s>every time it is run</s>(it turns out it's about half the time), with a StaleElementReferenceException. Whenever the test is run locally (headless or otherwise) the test will pass.

Interestingly, it's failing while running a method that is used in multiple other tests that will not hit this issue.

I have a callstack, but I'm really not sure how to go about debugging this one! Any advice please?!

```
   at OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriver.UnpackAndThrowOnError(Response errorResponse, String commandToExecute)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriver.Execute(String driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriver.InternalExecute(String driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.WebElement.Execute(String commandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.WebElement.get_Displayed()
   at SeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers.ExpectedConditions.<>c__DisplayClass6_0.<ElementToBeClickable>b__0(IWebDriver driver)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI.DefaultWait`1.Until[TResult](Func`2 condition, CancellationToken token)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI.DefaultWait`1.Until[TResult](Func`2 condition)
   at GembaCloud.Tests.Pages.BasePage.BasePageActions.WaitForElementToBeClickable(By element) in C:\agent\_work\53\s\GembaCloud.Tests\Pages\BasePage.cs:line 205
   at GembaCloud.Tests.Pages.BasePage.BasePageActions.GetTable(By byTable, Int32 firstDataRowIndex) in C:\agent\_work\53\s\GembaCloud.Tests\Pages\BasePage.cs:line 259
   at GembaCloud.Tests.Pages.GembaIntelligencePage.GembaIntelligencePageActions.GetGembaIntelligenceTable() in C:\agent\_work\53\s\GembaCloud.Tests\Pages\Home\GembaIntelligencePage.cs:line 52
   at GembaCloud.Tests.Pages.GembaIntelligencePage.GembaIntelligencePageActions.ExpandGembaIntelligenceTableRow(Int32 rowNumber) in C:\agent\_work\53\s\GembaCloud.Tests\Pages\Home\GembaIntelligencePage.cs:line 79
   at GembaCloud.Tests.TestClasses.UserRolePageElementAuthorisationTests.reporting_user_should_not_have_access_to_intelligence_dropdown_create_action_button() in C:\agent\_work\53\s\GembaCloud.Tests\TestClasses\UserRolePageElementAuthorisationTests.cs:line 115
```

Is there something obviously wrong here? Thanks!

Here's the code of the items in the callstack. GembaIntelligencePage class first:

```
            public void ExpandGembaIntelligenceTableRow(int rowNumber)
            {
                this.ExpandTableRow(this.GetGembaIntelligenceTable(), rowNumber);
            }

            public IList<IWebElement> GetGembaIntelligenceTable()
            {
                return this.GetTable(_elements.byGembaIntelligenceTable, 1);
            }
```

BasePage class second:

```
            protected IList<IWebElement> GetTable(By byTable, int firstDataRowIndex)
            {
                //firstDataRowIndex is so we only return the table rows that we need
                this.WaitForElementToBeClickable(byTable);
                IWebElement table = _driver.FindElement(byTable);

                IList<IWebElement> listOfDataTableRows = table.FindElements(By.CssSelector("tr")).Skip(firstDataRowIndex -1).ToList();

                return listOfDataTableRows;
            }

            protected void WaitForElementToBeClickable(By element)
            {
                WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(_driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
                wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(element));
            }
```

Comment: Update the question with your code trials.

Comment: please add your code and if possible, the url too so that it can be analyzed. thanks

Comment: the only thing that jumps out at me is the use of .skip() and .tolist()... doesn't seem like you should be doing that.  findElements is already going to return a list of webelement references.   Might be that ExpandTableRow is called more than once.  (triggers DOM change that doesn't affect clickability of table?)

Comment: Thanks, @pcalkins, I shall look into that shortly

Answer (score 0):

Change the Timeout value to a higher value (for example from 10 change it to 30) and tell us if it works:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(_driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));
```

Comment: Same issue. That didn't do anything, sadly